# ACF : date ISO to Timestamp don't give the right minutes

Tags: wordpress, date, timestamp, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently doing a website with ACF plugin. I get some data from an API (I have a json result).

In this result, I get this **2019-05-02T09:00:00Z**. I need to add this into my ACF field. This is almost working thanks to the **strtotime()** function.

But instead of having this result : **02/05/2019 09:00**, I have this one : **02/05/2019 09:05**

What adjustment should I make to fix that (it's a Wordpress site, so in PHP only please) ?

Edit : my ACF function :

```
  update_field('field_5bcce1711c3d5', $arrayParam["end"], $eventIdDB);
```

I've seen on forum that ACF is working with unix timestamp

Comment: so, you are 5 minutes of everytime?

Comment: seems like it is working fine? https://www.tehplayground.com/vFlAWRlOmcMj5mM8

Comment: Can you show me how json object?

Comment: `$realTime = date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime("2019-05-02T09:00:00Z"));` = `02/05/2019 09:00`

Comment: Stender, it depend (so no, not always). I'll try your link

Comment: You should show your function, where you add it into ACF - that might be the problem - Also, make sure that ACF is saving it as Unix time.

Comment: your solution isn't working, I'll updated my post